# JavaMail Issue : Can't send command to SMTP host

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I'm trying to do java mail and im getting an error "Cant send command to SMTP host". Any help would be appreciated. And any future problems' solutions if possible.
The exact Exception is

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Can't send command to SMTP host;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.SocketException: Connection closed by remote host
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:2106)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:2093)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.close(SMTPTransport.java:1184)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:197)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
    at TestEmail.main(TestEmail.java:45)
    at __SHELL17.run(__SHELL17.java:6)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at bluej.runtime.ExecServer$3.run(ExecServer.java:774)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection closed by remote host
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.checkWrite(SSLSocketImpl.java:1186)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:43)
    at com.sun.mail.util.TraceOutputStream.write(TraceOutputStream.java:114)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:65)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:123)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:2104)
    ... 11 more
```

My code is as follows

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;
import javax.activation.*;

// Send a simple, single part, text/plain e-mail
public class TestEmail {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // SUBSTITUTE YOUR EMAIL ADDRESSES HERE!!!
        String to = "my gmail account whose name i removed for publicity";
        String from = "my hotmail account whose name i removed for publicity";
        // SUBSTITUTE YOUR ISP'S MAIL SERVER HERE!!!
        String host = "smtp.live.com";

        // Create properties, get Session
        Properties props = new Properties();

        // If using static Transport.send(),
        // need to specify which host to send it to
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        // To see what is going on behind the scene
        props.put("mail.debug", "true");
        Session session = Session.getInstance(props);

        try {
            // Instantiatee a message
            Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);

            //Set message attributes
            msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
            InternetAddress[] address = {new InternetAddress(to)};
            msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, address);
            msg.setSubject("Test E-Mail through Java");
            msg.setSentDate(new Date());

            // Set message content
            msg.setText("This is a test of sending a " +
                        "plain text e-mail through Java.\n" +
                        "Here is line 2.");

            //Send the message
            Transport.send(msg);
        }
        catch (MessagingException mex) {
            // Prints all nested (chained) exceptions as well
            mex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "And any future problems' solutions if possible" -- really?

Comment: Well I mean like I put in "mail.smtp.auth" earlier and got a username and password error so thats what i mean

Comment: THe stack trace says "Connection closed by remote host".  You are going to have to use Wireshark to capture the traffic and find out the exact sequence of events.  What happens if you manually telnet to the mail server and try a mail session?

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not too familiar with SMTP and mail so I didn't exactly understand what you just said. Can you please de-techify that? :)

Comment: I posted an answer below.  However, until you understand a lot more about SMTP and TLS you're not going to be able to make progress.

Comment: @JimGarrison that is not very helpful - It would be useful to show how to correct this for jenkins

Comment: @Tim Did you post your Jenkins mail configuration on SuperUser? That's where you will be most likely to get help with a problem specific to Jenkins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server requires STARTTLS. Here's what I get if I do a manual SMTP session with telnet:

```
220 BLU0-SMTP122.phx.gbl Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service, Version: 6.0.3790.4675 ready at  Mon, 18 Jul 2011 17:08:14 -0700
HELO jhmg.net
250 BLU0-SMTP122.phx.gbl Hello [70.123.155.64]
MAIL FROM:<zzz@zzz.com>
530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first
```

This server does not accept unencrypted connections

Comment: Ok so you are saying that I need to encrypt my connection?

Comment: How exactly would I go about this? Im sorry if i sound dumb or something Im just new to mail and stuff

Comment: @JimGarrison the link is broken, can u find it ? thanks!

Comment: @Globmont did you find how to encrypt ur connection?

Answer (score 13):

Today I gone through this same issue.  But for me the issue is, in smtp server TLS was not enabled. So I have changed the mail properties like this.
`mail.smtp.starttls.enable=false`

Now every thing is working good for me.

Comment: Can you tell where do set this in jenkins?

Comment: I am also confused about where to set this up. I found this question since I am having the same problem in jenkins

Comment: You can set it in Jenkins -> Configuration -> Global Properties

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I was able to find the root problem after I enabled mailer debugging.

Different ways to enable mailer debugging:

`java -Dmail.debug=true ...`

```
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
props.put("mail.debug", "true");
```

Jenkins config (/etc/default/jenkins):

`JAVA_ARGS="-Dmail.smtp.starttls.enable=true -Dmail.debug=true"`

More info: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-135477.html

My particular error was that I had an incorrect address in the "from:" line when the email was created.  Google "G Suite" (google apps for business) requires the from-address to be in the same domain as the account owner. Eg. mycompanyname.com

The mailer debug revealed:

`MAIL FROM:<jenkins-pipeline@bogusdomain.com>
550-5.7.1 Invalid credentials for relay [192.168.42.42]. The IP address you've
550-5.7.1 registered in your G Suite SMTP Relay service doesn't match domain of
550-5.7.1 the account this email is being sent from. If you are trying to relay
550-5.7.1 mail from a domain that isn't registered under your G Suite account`

Comment: and what u did to fix it?

Comment: I used my GSuite domain in the From: line to fix it

Answer (score 0):

Try adding from address

mail.setFromAddress("Name ");

Answer (score 0):

You need to set ssl trust to smtp.gmail.com

```
properties.put("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", "smtp.gmail.com");
```

and Authenticator as a parameter for session

```
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties,new javax.mail.Authenticator(){
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {

                return new PasswordAuthentication(
                        sender, senderPassword);// Specify the Username and the PassWord
            }
        });
```

Answer (score -1):

Added this line for O365. Works fine now.

sslMailProps.put("mail.smtp.ssl.enable", "true");

Comment: please provide more information about the solution you provide