# Can't send command to SMTP host While sending mail

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

While trying to send mail, it is getting connected to smtp server but then i get the error "Can't send command to SMTP host". Below are the logs after enabling debug.

```
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "smtxxxxxxxxxaclecloud.com", port 25, isSSL false
220 smtpcxxxxx.net ESMTP smtp-in
DEBUG SMTP: connected to host "smxxxxxxxxxxxecloud.com", port: 25

EHLO RAXXXA-IN
250-smtxxxxxxdynback.net
250-STARTTLS
250 Ok
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "STARTTLS", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "Ok", arg ""
STARTTLS
220 Ready to start TLS
EHLO RAJXXHA-IN
The email was not sent.
Error message: Can't send command to SMTP host
```

Below is my code snippet.

```java
Properties props = System.getProperties();
props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
props.put("mail.smtp.port", PORT);

//props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.enable", "true"); //the default value is false if not set
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.auth.login.disable", "true");  //the default authorization order is "LOGIN PLAIN DIGEST-MD5 NTLM". 'LOGIN' must be disabled since Email Delivery authorizes as 'PLAIN'
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");   //TLSv1.2 is required
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.required", "true");  //Oracle Cloud Infrastructure required
try {
    // Create a Session object to represent a mail session with the specified properties.
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);
    session.setDebug(true);
    // Create a message with the specified information.
    MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
    msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(FROM, FROMNAME));
    msg.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(TO));
    msg.setSubject(SUBJECT);
    msg.setContent(BODY, "text/html");

    // Create a transport.
    Transport transport = session.getTransport();

    // Send the message.

    System.out.println("Sending Email now...standby...");

    // Connect to OCI Email Delivery using the SMTP credentials specified.
    transport.connect(HOST, SMTP_USERNAME, SMTP_PASSWORD);

    // Send email.
    transport.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());
    System.out.println("Email sent!");
} catch (Exception ex) {
    System.out.println("The email was not sent.");
    System.out.println("Error message: " + ex.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Is this a possible duplicate of [JavaMail Issue : Can't send command to SMTP host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6740838/javamail-issue-cant-send-command-to-smtp-host)?

Comment: no it is not. I have seen all related links found no solution

Comment: Then that would be information worthwhile to be mentioned in your description.

Comment: Just a guess, you're not calling ``saveChanges`` on your ``MimeMessage`` ``msg``. Also you may want to look at [the most common mistakes people make when using JavaMail](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#commonmistakes) and other JavaMail FAQs. Also ___including the stacktrace___ from the exception may be helpful.

Comment: Care to follow up on your question? Since you stated that the existing Q/A didn't solve your problem, it'd be worthwhile to track this problem down (and help others in the future). However, if it was "just some random mistake" then consider removing this question again.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't set the HOST variable in the "props" object

```
Properties props = System.getProperties();
props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
```

Add this line here: -

```
props.put("mail.smtp.host", HOST);
```

```
props.put("mail.smtp.port", PORT);
//props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.enable", "true"); //the default value is false if not set
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.auth.login.disable", "true");  //the default authorization order is "LOGIN PLAIN DIGEST-MD5 NTLM". 'LOGIN' must be disabled since Email Delivery authorizes as 'PLAIN'
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");   //TLSv1.2 is required
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.required", "true");  //Oracle Cloud Infrastructure required
try {
    // Create a Session object to represent a mail session with the specified properties.
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);
    session.setDebug(true);
    // Create a message with the specified information.
    MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
    msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(FROM, FROMNAME));
    msg.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(TO));
    msg.setSubject(SUBJECT);
    msg.setContent(BODY, "text/html");

    // Create a transport.
    Transport transport = session.getTransport();

    // Send the message.

    System.out.println("Sending Email now...standby...");

    // Connect to OCI Email Delivery using the SMTP credentials specified.
    transport.connect(HOST, SMTP_USERNAME, SMTP_PASSWORD);

    // Send email.
    transport.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());
    System.out.println("Email sent!");
} catch (Exception ex) {
    System.out.println("The email was not sent.");
    System.out.println("Error message: " + ex.getMessage());
}
```

I hope this help.